# Error when trying to extract specific columns/rows from Pandas dataframe using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have been taking online classes at datacamp for Python data science, but when I take the same code that I use on there and run it on my computer (as opposed to their website), I am getting errors that I do not understand.  I am using Spyder and Python 3.6.

The goal of my code is to import a .csv file, extract two rows and two columns from the pandas dataframe and print out the results.  From there I can graph the data on a histogram, and then expand it.  But first, I have to get the basics to work.  The code I have been using is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('drinks.csv')
df1 = df.loc[['USA', 'Germany'], ['country', 'beer_servings']]
print(df1)
```

The error I get is:

```
KeyError: "None of [['USA', 'Germany']] are in the [index]"
```

In case anyone wants to see the data I am using, the link I used to download it is: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/alcohol-consumption/drinks.csv

Even if I go as simple as I possibly can and just extract a single row, I still get the same error (as seen below).  The same exact thing happens if I try to extract a single column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('drinks.csv')
df1 = df.loc[['USA']]
print(df1)
```

The error is:

```
KeyError: "None of [['USA']] are in the [index]"
```

Is there something i'm missing?

https://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/

This is the website I was using to try and understand what I was doing wrong, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I am missing.  I understand that this is probably a very trivial problem, but please if you have any advice I would love to hear it, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['country'].isin(['USA', 'Germany']), ['country', 'beer_servings']]
```

Or, you can `set_index` first to make your existing code work.

```
df = df.set_index('country')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the country column to the index first:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('drinks.csv').set_index('country')
df1 = df.loc[['USA', 'Germany'], 'beer_servings']
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
country
USA        249
Germany    346
Name: beer_servings, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df.loc[df['country'].isin(['USA', 'Germany']), ['country', 'beer_servings']]
     country  beer_servings
65   Germany            346
184      USA            249
```